# "Block If without End If" error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm getting a compile error for this code:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Text = "log off" Then
Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -l", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Logging off"
If TextBox1.Text = "shutdown" Then
Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -s", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Shutting Down"
If TextBox1.Text = "restart" Then
Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -r", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Restarting"

Else
MsgBox "Command Not Defined",vbCritical
End Sub
```

Now it comes up with this Error Message of "Block If without End If".
Why?

Comment: what you're doing is self terminating `IF` statement by putting the condition and result in one line. the last `Else` is floating since all `IF` statements above already terminated. @simoco already showed the alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have missed `End If`:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If TextBox1.Text = "log off" Then
        Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -l", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Logging off"
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "shutdown" Then
        Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -s", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Shutting Down"
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "restart" Then
        Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -r", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Restarting"
    Else
        MsgBox "Command Not Defined", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub
```

Actually in your code you will always have `TextBox2.Text` equals to `"Restarting"`. That's why you should use `ElseIf` statement.

You could use `Select Case` statement as well:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Select Case TextBox1.Text
        Case "log off"
            Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -l", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Logging off"
        Case "shutdown"
            Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -s", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Shutting Down"
        Case "restart"
            Shell "cmd.exe /c shutdown -r", vbHide: TextBox2.Text = "Restarting"
        Case Else
            MsgBox "Command Not Defined", vbCritical
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 for also suggesting select case :)